# Is it a bad idea to virtualize DC, DNS and DHCP?

Tags: networking, virtualization, domain-controller

I'm planning to set up a small environment with a Domain Controller, DNS and DHCP using Windows Server. My question is in other words not for a huge world-spanning enterprise network solution (and I believe that matters).

Is it a bad idea to use a single virtualisation host, with one virtual machine for each of these server roles on the same host?

Or for that matter, one VM running all three roles and other VM's for other purposes on the same host?

Comment: No. No, it's not a bad idea.

Comment: Vote to reopen. Particularly as there are issues and the MS guideliney have changed over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can do that safely. Even in SMB segment these roles sometimes are running on the same server (physical or virtual)